# Get input value and pass it to another input using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 input in my form and I want it like this:

The value of the first input must be the value of the second input.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input1" onKeyUp="getVal()" name="" value="" />
<input type="text" id="input2" name="" value="" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getVal(){
  document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  }
</script>
```

My current code is not working. Can somebody help?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but both the `language` and `type` attributes on the `script` tag are superfluous.

Comment: Its typo you assigning blank value of `input2` on keypup of `input1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getVal(){
  document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  }
</script>
```

#### Using Jquery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getVal(){
  $("#input2").val($("#input1").val());
  }
</script>
```

By the way, why are you keeping the name as blank? I mean, `name=""`?

Answer (score 1):

This was backward, 1 was overwriting itself.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getVal(){
        document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We know very well its not your question and your solution is perfect. But still we are voting to close question. Because OP is asking for just typo correction.

Comment: Oh that was just weird, with the other comment from someone else, I was just like woah what happened, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the value on `input2` to the value of `input1` then you need to swap the ids.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getVal(){
        document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You inverted you value attribution, meaning that each time you release a key in input1, the value of input1 is overwritter by input 2.
Try this :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getVal(){
      document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  }
</script>
```